# img url by id bbcode

Tags: php, regex, bbcode

I want to get the link from src atribute by specific ID

For example I have following bbcode tags:

```
[img alt="" src="http://google.com" id="image"]
[img src="http://google.com" id="image2" alt=""]
[img id="image3" src="http://google.com" alt=""]
```

I tried with `\[img(?:[^]]+src="(.+?)"[^]]+(?:id|class)="image"|[^]]+(?:id|class)="image"[^]]+src="(.+?)")`

but for the second image it doesnt work

https://regex101.com/r/7owPlM/3

Comment: Remove "singleline" flag.

Comment: @horcrux yeah that's the problem because i have a single line text... maybe can i add a <br/> after each ] ?

Comment: Or just use `[^]]` instead of the two `.`

Comment: @chris85 I have BBCodes

Comment: @horcrux I don't understand.. hmmm

Comment: @chris85 I had BBCodes from the beginning, after some comments I realised that BBCodes can not be parsed as HTML. That's why I need REGEX

Comment: [`\[img(?:[^]]+src="([^]]+?)"[^]]+(?:id|class)="image2"|[^]]+(?:id|class)="image2"[^]]+src="([^]]+?)")`](https://regex101.com/r/7owPlM/5)

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this(https://regex101.com/r/SDYM7u/3):

```
\[img\s(?:.*?src="(.*?)".*?)?id="image"(?:.*?src="(.*?)".*?)?[^\]]*]
```

using flags g and m.The only downside is that in this case you will need to check both capture group 1 and 2 to find your url. When src precedes id attribute then the match is stored in Group 1 but when id attribute precedes src then the url is stored in group 2.